# Can i creatte a form in a shape specified in the image link below?

Tags: wpf-controls

I wants to create a form in a specified format where main window area will have some common links or buttons to all pages and the page area is where all the pages will be shown. Is this possible in wpf ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by using tab item and frames. You can have an idea using:

```
<TabItem Header="about" Name="aboutTab">
    <TabControl>
       <TabItem Header="REGISTRATION" Name="subTabRegistration">
          <Grid>
             <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ClipToBounds="True" JournalOwnership="Automatic" Source="Pages/register-activate.xaml"  x:Name="frameRegistration" />
          </Grid>
       </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
  </TabItem>
```